# Why gettimg error: undefined reference to `sqrt' when passing a variable, but it compiled successfully when passing constant as an argument

Tags: c, gcc, undefined-reference, sqrt

This program is giving "undefined reference of sqrt" error:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int main(){
int/float/double x=8;
int y=sqrt(x);  //error
printf("%d",y);
}
```

But when I uses constant value 8, as an argument, it works fine.

```
int main(){
int y=sqrt(8);  // This is working fine.
printf("%d",y);
}
```

using command : `gcc <filename>.c`

Comment: working fine on Codeblocks.

Comment: Did you link the math library with `-lm`?

Comment: If the argument is constant, the actual function is not needed.

Comment: @DavidBowling with -lm ,  its working

Comment: @harold could you explain why its working with constant

Comment: `int y=sqrt(8);` can yield a value at compile time, and some compilers do this. I wouldn't rely on this behavior.